# Wordpress sql query to run in frontend return no results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to display the following in Wordpress frontend through a plugin, but unfortunately I can not show the results.
I only get the table headers.

Is there something that I am missing out?

```
global $wpdb;    
$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($SQLstring);
    $content = '<table>';
    $content .= '</tr><th>first</th>';
        $content .= '<th>second</th>';
        $content .= '<th>third</th></tr>';


    foreach ( $results AS $row ) {
        $content .= '<tr><td>d' . $row->post_date_gmt . '</td>';
            $content .= '<td>s' . $row->post_title . '</td>';
            $content .= '<td>a' . $row->post_status . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</table>';

echo $content;
```

Comment: have you run  the query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @nbk of course!

Comment: the query as you posted runs in wp without a hinch, so when you got no errors(have you enabled it) then there are no records, which means you are usually on a different database

Comment: Have you checked your table prefix? Better is to use -> "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts}"

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your table prefix? Better is to use:

```
"SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts}"
```